# How to retrieve auto incremented id in rails 4.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently i am working on rails 4.1,

I have a model called `accounts.rb`,

```
account = Account.create :name => 'test' :info => 'test'
```

So this statement is saving to database,
  Then i am using "account.id" which auto increment id in accounts table.

But that is not working and showing following error,

```
undefined method `id' for "":String
```

But this was worked in rails 1.9 version .

Please help me.

Comment: Aren't you missing a comma there?

Comment: just use `account.id`after record creation

Comment: I don't see any problem, works for me just fine. can you post `accounts.rb`?

Comment: class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Above is the file.

Comment: Are you saying you used `"account.id"` i mean as a string?

Comment: @Sergio Tulensev : comma where ??

Comment: here - `Account.create :name => 'test' :info => 'test'`

Comment: Yes. comma is there @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @YellaGoud: not in the question, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: rails 1.9 or ruby 1.9?

Comment: I think so you are have updated account variable with string try to change name of your variable like account_obj = Account.create :name => 'test' :info => 'test' and then try account_obj.id

Answer (score 1):

**Object**

Your method seems correct; your syntax seems to have an issue

```
undefined method `id' for "":String
```

This basically means you're calling the `id` method on an object which is just a string, an empty one at that.

I would therefore say the problem is not to do with your `auto increment` number, it's to do with how you're calling the `id` of the new object

--

**Create**

The *standard* way to do this would be to use the following:

```
#controller
account = Account.create({name: "test", info: "test"})
return account.id
```

According to the [create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class) documentation, this *should* work for you. If it doesn't, you may wish to use the `.new` with `.save` methods, like this:

```
#controller
account = Account.new({name: "test", info: "test"})
if account.save
  return account.id
end
```